# Applescript to hide an app/alias

Tags: mac, terminal, applescript, automator

I am trying to write an application using Applescript in Automator that runs on terminal on a Mac Air running Sierra. The account using the application has parental controls set, but I need to give them access to terminal to run the application. Ultimately, we don't want the users on the account to have access to terminal. So, I am trying to figure out a way to delete or hide the alias.

I am able to delete the alias using the script below, but when they try to use the application again, it doesn't work because Terminal is no longer available:

```
tell application "System Events" to delete alias "/Path/to/Library/Managed Items/My Applications/Terminal"
end tell
```

When I tried to hide the alias, as seen below, I get an error stating that the process can't be set to false:

```
tell application "System Events" 
        set visible of application process "/Path/to/Library/Managed Items/My Applications/Terminal" to false
end tell
```

Not sure if I can load Terminal at the beginning of the script and then delete it at the end OR if there is a way to hide the alias.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my entire code:

```
on run {input, parameters}

tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using option down
end tell --used to deactivate trackpad

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "Terminal"
    do script "su <admin account>" --not root
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "<password>" & return
        delay 2
        keystroke "sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/" & return --used to disable keyboard
        delay 2
        keystroke "<password>" & return
        delay 2
        keystroke "exit" & return
        delay 2
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script with command "rm -R release.zip; rm -R release; wget https://URL/for/webserver/release.zip; unzip release.zip; rm -rf __MACOSX" in window 1 --deletes old configuration .zip file and folder; downloads new configuration files; unzips new configuration files
            delay 15
        end tell
        tell application "Terminal"
            do script with command "su <admin account>" in window 1
            delay 2
            tell application "System Events"
                keystroke "<password>" & return
                delay 2
                keystroke "sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTCKeyboard.kext/" & return --reloads keyboard
                delay 2
                keystroke "exit" & return
                delay 2
            end tell
            tell application "Terminal"
                do script with command "release/pc-release-mac.command --config config.properties; exit" in window 1 --Launches print release software
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    delay 2
    tell application "Terminal"
        quit
    end tell
end tell
end tell
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 21 using option down
end tell --reactivates trackpad

return input
end run
```

Any improvements would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to scripting, so I've muddled through most of this.

Comment: This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/335435). For this app you're running, are you just using Terminal to start it, or do you actually need Terminal to interact with it? And do you need to prevent users from using Terminal, or from using the *shell* (e.g. Bash)?

Comment: Currently, I have it interact with Terminal, but I'm not opposed to running bash. I'm just not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the “do Shell script” command in an AppleScript, the command will be executed without launching terminal.app   here is a “do shell script” AppleScript example to try out.  Notice that terminal never gets launched.

```
display dialog (do shell script "curl ifconfig.co") with icon 2 buttons "OK" default button 1 with title "Your Current IP Address Is.." giving up after 5
```

Comment: Background on the project. I am trying to install a print release station on a Mac Air to be used in my school district. I don't want the end users to be able to stop the script from running, so I've disabled keyboard and the trackpad while the script is running. I use wget to download the configuration files from our web server because I couldn't get curl to work properly; the file it downloaded wouldn't unzip correctly. I've posted the entire script at the bottom of my original question.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments posted by 8bittree and wch1zpink, I decided to look into using Applescript to run shell scripts. I was able to get everything I needed in on easy, simple script that doesn't require terminal.  My issue before trying to use shell script was I had left the default scripting in the window. After I removed it, the code below did exactly what I needed:

```
do shell script "rm -R /Users/<account>/release.zip; rm -R /Users/<account>/release; curl -L https://URL/to/webserver/release.zip -o /Users/<account>/release.zip; unzip -o /Users/<account>/release.zip -d /Users/<account>; rm -rf /Users/<account>/__MACOSX; /Users/<account>/release/pc-release-mac.command --config config.properties"
```

Doesn't require Terminal; doesn't require disabling the keyboard; doesn't require disabling the trackpad; doesn't require passwords to be hard coded.

Thank you both for giving me a direction!!!

Comment: If you have found peoples' answers to your questions have been useful or helpful, just thank them by upvotting their answers.